# dynamically generating HTML divs/JS scripts with Python/GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates

I am building a webapp and I would like to be able to dynamically render out divs/scripts in my index.html given certain conditions. An abstraction of what I would like to do is the following:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, q):
        script = "<script>function display_alert(){ {alert('Hello world!'}}</script> <div>hello world</div>"
        if q is None:
            q = 'index.html'
        path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
        self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.write (template.render (path, {
        "script" : script
        }))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

The HTML is a simple index.html file that contains {{script}}. When it renders out, it looks like this:

[image]

Why isn't the HTML rendering what I gave it correctly? I tried running the "script" variable through simplejson.dumps, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Html is escaped by default in django templates

in django this is accomplished with the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template filter

`{{ script|safe }}`

are you using django to render your templates? or a different engine?

Comment: Thanks, this works! I ultimately solved my problem by using a for loop in the django template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/